# Ways to dynamically render a real world 3d environment in Unity3D

Tags: c#, 3d, unity-game-engine, google-earth

Using Unity3D and C# I am attempting to display a 3d version of a real world location. Inside my Unity3D app, the user will specify the GPS coordinates of a location, then my app will have to generate a 3d plane(anything doesn't have to be a plane) of that location. The plane will show a 500 metre by 500 metre 3d snapshot of that location.

**How would you suggest I achieve this in Unity3D? What methodology would you use to achieve this?**

*NOTE: I understand that this is a very difficult endevour(to render real world locations dynamically in Unity3d) so I expect to perform many actions to achieve this. I just don't know of all the technologies out there and which would be best for my needs*

For example:

> Suggested methodology 1:
>
> - Prompt user to specify GPS coords
> - Use Google earth API and HTTP to programmatically obtain a .khm file
>     describing that location(Not sure if
>     google earth provides that capability
>
>   - does it?)
> - Unzip the .khm so I have the .dae file
> - Convert that file to a .3ds file using ??? third party converter(is
>     there a converter that exists?)
> - Import .3ds into Unity3D at runtime as a plane(is this possible)?
>
> Suggested methodology 2:
>
> - Prompt user to specify GPS coords
> - Use Google earth API and HTTP to programmatically obtain a .khm file
>     describing that location(Not sure if
>     google earth provides that capability
>
>   - does it?)
> - Unzip the .khm so I have the .dae file
> - Parse .dae file using my own C# parser I will write(do you think its
>     possible to write a .dae parser that
>     can parse the .dae into an array of
>     Vector3 that describe the height map
>     of that location?)
> - Dynamically create a plane in Unity3D and populate it with my
>     array/list of Vector3 points(is it
>     possible to create a plane this way?)
>     Maybe I am meant to create a mesh
>     instead of a plane?

**Can you think of any other ways I could render a real world 3d environment in Unity3D?**

Answer (score 0):

No service available has a detailed 3d map of an area given gps coordinates. Google has a super simple height map that they draw and then map their aerial pictures onto, but even if you could get programmatic access to that it would look terrible if you were at street level. If you're okay with a horrid level of detail (like you're going to be viewing this from high up or something) maybe it would be feasible, but not as any kind of first person street level experience.